# i need to split this paragraph into points

Tags: javascript, html

"The article "5 Ways to Increase Website Traffic" provides valuable insights on how to drive more traffic to your website. The key focus is on implementing effective strategies to attract and engage users. The six key points are as follows: \n\n1. Utilize SEO Techniques: Incorporate search engine optimization tactics, such as optimizing keywords, meta tags, and headers, to improve your website's visibility and ranking on search engines.\n2. Create High-Quality Content: Develop compelling and informative content that resonates with your target audience and encourages them to share it, increasing the likelihood of attracting more visitors.\n3. Leverage Social Media: Actively engage with your audience on social media platforms by sharing engaging content, promoting your website, and interacting with users to drive traffic to your site.\n4. Utilize Email Marketing: Develop an efficient email marketing strategy to keep your subscribers informed about your latest content, products, or services, and encourage them to visit your website.\n5. Collaborate with Influencers: Connect with influencers in your industry and collaborate on content, partnerships, or promotions to tap into their audience and increase your website's exposure .\n6. Optimize Website Performance: Ensure your website is fast-loading, mobile-friendly, and user-friendly, as visitors are more likely to stay and explore if your site provides a seamless browsing experience.\n\nImplementing these key strategies will help you attract more traffic to your website and improve your online presence."

I need to break these paragraphs into points in javascript

Comment: I don't really understand, improve your question, show us what you tried, what's the problem, and what you're expecting.

Comment: So you need to split the paragraph. So each array content is 1 sentence but if you split with `.`. Any number decimal will be splited too. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the string of text, the use of `\n` immediately preceding a number, I assume the question you intended to ask was:

> How can can I turn this text into something like a numbered list?

One approach is below with explanatory comments in the code.

First, using regular expressions:

```js
// utility function as an alias for both document.querySelector() (by default),
// and Element.querySelector() (which requires the Element to be passed as an
// argument):
const D = document,
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector);

// retrieving the first/only element in the document that matches the
// supplied selector; this may result in null if the element does
// not exist in the document:
let blockquote = get('blockquote');

// here we update the innerHTML of the <blockquote> (innerHTML because we're
// inserting <br> elements, not just manipulating the text),
// using String.prototype.replaceAll(); because the sequence we're looking
// for includes a back-slash - a string escape character - we have to escape
// the character itself, which is why we use "\\n" instead of "\n" (which would
// otherwise escape the "n" character, and prevent any matches):
blockquote.innerHTML = blockquote.textContent.replaceAll('\\n', '<br>');
```

```css
/*
  Utterly irrelevant CSS, this is just to make things a little "nicer"
*/
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <blockquote>"The article "5 Ways to Increase Website Traffic" provides valuable insights on how to drive more traffic to your website. The key focus is on implementing effective strategies to attract and engage users. The six key points are as follows: \n\n1. Utilize SEO Techniques: Incorporate search engine optimization tactics, such as optimizing keywords, meta tags, and headers, to improve your website's visibility and ranking on search engines.\n2. Create High-Quality Content: Develop compelling and informative content that resonates with your target audience and encourages them to share it, increasing the likelihood of attracting more visitors.\n3. Leverage Social Media: Actively engage with your audience on social media platforms by sharing engaging content, promoting your website, and interacting with users to drive traffic to your site.\n4. Utilize Email Marketing: Develop an efficient email marketing strategy to keep your subscribers informed about your latest content, products, or services, and encourage them to visit your website.\n5. Collaborate with Influencers: Connect with influencers in your industry and collaborate on content, partnerships, or promotions to tap into their audience and increase your website's exposure.\n6. Optimize Website Performance: Ensure your website is fast-loading, mobile-friendly, and user-friendly, as visitors are more likely to stay and explore if your site provides a seamless browsing experience.\n\nImplementing these key strategies will help you attract more traffic to your website and improve your online presence."</blockquote>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mgrt846x/).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).